# Theme Load Error

Tags: plugins, images, jquery, frontpage, nginx

For 2 days I'm struggling and hitting my head to find out the solution but no thing. 
The website isn't loading images on front-page and news-ticker not working at all.

I tried to re-uploading the theme more than once.
I tried disabling all plugins

Nothing the problem persist.

```
   function eff_post_image($size = ''){
    global $post;
    $image = '';
    //get the post thumbnail
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,  
    $size);
    $image = $image[0];
    if ($image) return $image;
    //if the post is video post and haven't a feutre image
    $type = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eff_article_type', true);
    $vtype = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eff_video_type', true);
    $vId = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eff_video_id', true);
    if($type == 'video') {
                    if($vtype == 'youtube') {
                      $image = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$vId.'/0.jpg';
                    } elseif ($vtype == 'vimeo') {
                    $hash = unserialize(wp_remote_get("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$vId.php"));
                      $image = $hash[0]['thumbnail_large'];
                    } elseif ($vtype == 'daily') {
                      $image = 'http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/'.$vId;
                    }
            }
    if ($image) return $image;
    //If there is still no image, get the first image from the post
    return eff_get_first_image();
    }
    function eff_get_first_image() {
      global $post, $posts;
      $first_img = '';
      ob_start();
      ob_end_clean();
      $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
      $first_img = $matches[1][0];

      if(empty($first_img)) {
        $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
      }
      return $first_img;
    }

    // First Image 
    function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

    if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
      $first_img = EFF_IMG . "/default.png";
    }
    return $first_img;
      }
```

Comment: *How* are you trying to display the images? Looks like the src for the logo is an `Array()` so something isn't right. As for the newticker I suggest looking at your JS console as there are some errors. Other than that it's always advised to [turn on debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) in case there are any PHP errors that are being supressed.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thanks for your comment. The images are parsed by php `<img itemprop="image" src="<?php echo post_image(); ?>" width="250" height="143" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />` Through Google Chrome I checked but I don't get exact error what is it

Comment: P.S. debugger already active but nothing shown

Comment: Edit your question with what the `post_image()` function included, code is difficult to read as comments.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee done please check up

Comment: This doesn't make much sense... If what you've posted is the `post_image()` function, this function is outputting HTML into  the `src` attribute where it should only return a URL... If this is a purchased theme your best bet is to contact the developers or support.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee please check post image function

Comment: For the logo, I would do `$image = post_image()` and see what the array contains. For the rest of the images on the page it looks like there's an internal style that says: `.post_thumb img { opacity: 0; }` you can find that in your source. The only reason I can think of doing that is if JQuery fade them in when the page is loaded so it looks smooth but what I would do is overwrite that in your css with `opacity: 1!important;`. Otherwise try and find what's putting that internal style in and remove it.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thank you for your support, I've disabled the fade in and now the image load is resolved but what about the news ticker it's not work any advise please :)